# Block calender entry with specific categories

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a Meeting / Appointment Item and make this form available with a set category.
I would like to be able to decide now which of them I enter in my calendar or not.

I'm a beginner in VBA and have a code to found my specific categories, that's work.

```
' Outputs all elements without set category
Sub SearchCategoryRestriction()
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim Filter As String
 Dim myNamespace As Namespace

 'This will return all items that have the set category.
 Filter = "[Categories] = 'myKeyword'"
 Set myNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
 Debug.Print myItems.Count

End Sub
```

Now my idea is, when I have found the item, I want to see the appointment and be able to decide if I want to add it to my calendar or not.

Edit:
Maybe i found a smart solution for my Problem here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-a-declined-meeting-on-my-calendar-24E81B9B-3906-4C02-8B63-F97B02161763
If i delete all income items with my set categories, i hope they will not be added to my calendar. 
Then I run the search script to find it in the list of objects to be deleted and show it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest using `Instr` function instead of comparing strings. The Categories string may contain other markers, not only your single one.

It is not clear what code is used for searching items with specific categories set, most probably you just iterate over all items in the folder which is not good. Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` to get only items that correspond to your conditions. For example:

```
Sub MoveItems()  
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder  
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myRestrictItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set myFolder = _  
        myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items  
    Set myRestrictItems = myItems.Restrict("[Categories] = 'testword'")  
    ' do whatever you need with items found, for example, move to a subfolder
    For i =  myRestrictItems.Count To 1 Step -1  
        myRestrictItems(i).Move myFolder.Folders("Business")  
    Next  
End Sub
```

The `Categories` field is of type keywords, which is designed to hold multiple values. When accessing it programmatically, the `Categories` field behaves like a `Text` field, and the string must match exactly. Values in the text string are separated by a comma and a space. This typically means that you cannot use the `Find` and `Restrict` methods on a keywords field if it contains more than one value. For example, if you have one contact in the Business category and one contact in the Business and Social categories, you cannot easily use the `Find` and `Restrict` methods to retrieve all items that are in the Business category. Instead, you can loop through all contacts in the folder and use the `Instr` function to test whether the string "Business" is contained within the entire keywords field.

A possible exception is if you limit the `Categories` field to two, or a low number of values. Then you can use the `Find` and `Restrict` methods with the OR logical operator to retrieve all items. For example (in pseudocode): "Business" OR "Business, Personal" OR "Personal, Business."

Pay attention to the fact that `Category` strings are not case-sensitive.

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the Items property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Comment: I change my search to without a for loop, hope that's what you've recommend to me.
Now I want to be asked if I want to add the found calendar entry with the category to my calendar or not.
I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You can use the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.move) method.

Comment: ok i try it, but have some problems. I need declare myItems as AppointmentItem (or MeetingItem) to use the move command "myItems.Move (olFolderDeletedItems)". Or is there another possibility